What is the difference between having or not having async keyword in the declaration of a Typescript method
I'm just wondering if the keyword async has any functional difference in a method declaration, if the method will be returning a Promise type.
For example:
async function a(): Promise<string> {
  return Promise.resolve("method a");
}

function b(): Promise<string> {
  return Promise.resolve("method b");
}

Is there any functional difference between having and not having the async keyword?

No difference worth considering. With that said a doesn't need to exist in this form, since there is no real reason to use Promise.resolve() if it's already async. It's just code padding.

There may be some minor implementation difference under the hood that I'm not aware of (and could differ by implementation), but functionally they do the same thing.  Both functions return a Promise which resolves to a string.
Note that in the example given the first function is redundant.  Which may have even been the source of the question in the first place.
This function is correct and returns a Promise<string>:
function b(): Promise<string> {
  return Promise.resolve("method b");
}

To achieve the same functionality using async you don't need the Promise:
async function a(): Promise<string> {
  return "method a";
}

An async function always implicitly returns a Promise.  If the value being returned isn't a Promise then it gets quietly wrapped in one.  Which allows for things like this:
async function a(): Promise<string> {
  if (someCondition) {
    return "method a";
  }
  return await someMethod(); // someMethod() itself returns a Promise<string>
}

Technically if the condition is truthy then the function only returns a string, and nothing asynchronous is happening.
Functionally this doesn't matter because the engine will ensure the returned string is wrapped in a Promise so consuming code can always treat the operation as asynchronous.
